# rails 4 - sort by number of votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So... I have images.  and those images have votes.

I currently have **image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  has_many :image_votes, dependent: :destroy

  default_scope { order(ci_lower_bound) }

  def taken_by? (photographer)
    self.user == photographer
  end

  def self.ci_lower_bound
    pos = image_votes.where(value: 1).size
    n = image_votes.size
    if n == 0
      return 0
    end
    z = 1.96
    phat = 1.0*pos/n
    (phat + z*z/(2*n) - z * Math.sqrt((phat*(1-phat)+z*z/(4*n))/n))/(1+z*z/n)
  end
end
```

I've been playing around with this... the only way to get default scope to work is to use a method with self.  I found that formula at http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html - how would I call this to make it work??

Comment: what is not working exactly ? what do you means by ut if more than 1 person votes for any given photo, that photo shows again for each person who voted ? and what do you expect ?

Comment: It looks hard to use this formula inside a SQL request. I would instead create a column for ci_lower_value in Image model, and use active record callbacks to update it every time a new vote is created.

Comment: that did it, @Baldrick.  I added an `after_save :ci_lower_bound` to **image_vote.rb**.  then update the rank attribute on the vote's image.  That will work for now! I think that will actually hold up better in the long run as well, because all the 'hard work' is done when voting, and not when trying to retrieve the images, which I'm thinking will be faster for the users.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new scope called `by_votes`, include `sum()` and [order](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) by this new column:

```
scope :by_votes, -> { select("#{Image.table_name}.*, sum(#{ImageVote.table_name}.votes) AS votes").order("votes DESC") }
```

Comment: i started off with a sum... but i liked that article, so I wanted to try to sort by that.